# RcppArmadillo: convert matrix subview to SEXP

Tags: r, rcpp

Is there a way to convert an `arma::subview<double>` into an `SEXP`? I have the following code after creating a matrix `X` in my `Rcpp` code:

```
  //.... MCMC loop
  if(i % skiplength == 0) {
    for(unsigned int k=0; k < X.n_rows; k++) {
      X(k,index) = y[k];
    }
    index = index + 1;
  }
  // return matrix of samples in columns
  return Rcpp::wrap(X.submat( arma::span(0, X.n_rows - 1) , arma::span(discard, X.n_cols-1)));
END_RCPP
}
```

But I'm getting an error message specifying: `cannot convert 'const arma::subview<double>' to SEXP in initialization`. Is there an easy fix to this?

### A reproducible example

```
reproducible = '
arma::subview<double> conv(arma::Mat<double> m) {
return m.submat(arma::span(0, m.n_rows),arma::span(0, m.n_cols));
}'

cppFunction(code = reproducible, depends = "RcppArmadillo", verbose = TRUE)
```

Comment: Can you make you code reproducible. otherwise you might want to first store the result of the `submat` call into an `arma::mat`, and then `wrap` that.

Comment: @RomainFrancois I edited my question to make a reproducible example. And I think you are correct, but I can't find a way to convert subview to matrix

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just figured this out, a subview is apparently castable to a matrix

I replaced

```
return Rcpp::wrap(X.submat( arma::span(0, X.n_rows - 1) , arma::span(discard, X.n_cols-1)));
```

with

```
arma::mat ret = X.submat(arma::span(0, X.n_rows - 1) , arma::span(discard, X.n_cols-1));
return Rcpp::wrap(ret);
```

And it compiles fine.

Comment: And if you want to be ambitious, you could submit a `wrap()` method that does this behind the scenes ... after which this will available more generally.

Comment: @DirkEddelbuettel that would be interesting, is there a process for submitting packages?

Comment: We're informal.  Write a patch, test it, send it to the rcpp-devel list for comments / review.

Comment: I've pushed an initial implementation of `wrap<subview>` which should avoid the extra copy from the sub view to the `arma::mat`